# Cannot listen to feature branches from Jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins

[image]

I have this setup in my jenkins git plugin and Build trigger is to Poll SCM `H/5 * * * *`, but the issue is when new feature branch is created it start checking out master rather than the feature branch.

```
Started by an SCM change
Building in workspace C:\JenkinsNew\workspace\mastervalidate
Cloning the remote Git repository
Cloning repository https://github.com/Nagendra080389/trailheadOrg.git
 > C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe init C:\JenkinsNew\workspace\mastervalidate # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from https://github.com/Nagendra080389/trailheadOrg.git
 > C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe --version # timeout=10
using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials 
 > C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe fetch --tags --progress https://github.com/Nagendra080389/trailheadOrg.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
 > C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe config remote.origin.url https://github.com/Nagendra080389/trailheadOrg.git # timeout=10
 > C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe config --add remote.origin.fetch +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=10
 > C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe config remote.origin.url https://github.com/Nagendra080389/trailheadOrg.git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from https://github.com/Nagendra080389/trailheadOrg.git
using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials 
 > C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe fetch --tags --progress https://github.com/Nagendra080389/trailheadOrg.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
Seen branch in repository origin/feature/US-001
Seen branch in repository origin/master
Seen 2 remote branches
 > C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe show-ref --tags -d # timeout=10
Checking out Revision 58a1a824ab6508a83bc975dfdc9f6bf50e4a142f (origin/master)
 > C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe checkout -f 58a1a824ab6508a83bc975dfdc9f6bf50e4a142f
```

Is there something I am missing in configuration, I only want to listen to features branches.

Comment: How about `*/features/*`?

Comment: Nope even that does not work.  Also the ${GIT_BRANCH} is echoed as origin/master

Comment: In the log the feature branch is `origin/feature/US-001` while in the pattern it's featureS. Maybe `**/feature/*` works.

Comment: @ElpieKay Actually the above suggestion worked. You can write that as an answer.